# Soup parser not able to extract class information

Tags: beautifulsoup

While running query:
`soup.find_all('div')`

I get results:

```
<div class="class-link">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="abc" style="text-decoration: underline">
                                                    See all</a>
</div>, <div class="sota-table-link">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="abc" style="text-decoration: underline">
                                                    See all</a>
</div>, <div class="class-link">
```

Though when I run: `soup.find_all('div', _class='class-link')` I get empty list.

What causes this issue and how can I get correct div?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `class` as key-value pairs to the `attrs` parameter, instead, like this:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'class-link'})
```

Result:

```
[<div class="class-link">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="abc" style="text-decoration: underline">
                                                    See all</a>
</div>, <div class="class-link"></div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) documentation

it must be `class_` and not `_class`

So you code mus be changed to

```
print(soup.find_all("div", class_="class-link"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find css selectors a lot cleaner

```
soup.select('div.class-link')
```

where the . is a css [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)